# How to stop exception from searching Unavailable/no cities?

Tags: java, android, exception, toast, weather

I have a Weather app that searches for any city typed on the `EditText` and it works very well.
But the problem is that the app crashes and reports `"(my app) has stopped"` on my phone whenever I search for an unavailable city or I leave the `EditText` empty and click the search button(this only happens when I search an unavailable city/no city is searched), It can search any valid city correctly.

Here's what my Logcat displays(only when an unavailable city is searched):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.viz.lightweatherforecast.Retrofit.Example$Main com.viz.lightweatherforecast.Retrofit.Example.getMain()' on a null object reference
        at com.viz.lightweatherforecast.FirstFragment$1.onResponse(FirstFragment.java:104)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

and

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.viz.lightweatherforecast.first.PrettyTime com.viz.lightweatherforecast.Retrofit.Example.getDt()' on a null object reference
        at com.viz.lightweatherforecast.Activity.HomeActivity$1$2.onResponse(HomeActivity.java:100)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

when no city is searched(`EditText` is empty).

So I'm trying to stop the exception responsible for that and as well write a toast/message to tell the user "`no city found`" when an unavailable/no city is searched.
Please how do I do that? So far, I've tried adding:

```
Log.d(TAG, "No City found");
```

on my

```
@Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

the method in HomeActivity, but it still crashes.

Here's my specific code:

HomeActivity.java:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // User current time
    TextView time_field;
    ImageView Search;
    EditText textfield;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    // For scheduling background image change
    public static int count=0;
    int[] drawable =new int[]{R.drawable.dubai,R.drawable.central_bank_of_nigeria,R.drawable.eiffel_tower,R.drawable.hong_kong,R.drawable.statue_of_liberty};
    Timer _t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        time_field = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        Search = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        textfield = findViewById(R.id.textfield);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        assert navHostFragment != null;
        final NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
                firstFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());

                            constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
                            constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dubai);
                            _t = new Timer();
                            _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // run on ui thread
                                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                        if (count < drawable.length) {

                                            constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                                            count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }, 5000, 5000);
                        }

            private void getWeatherData(String name) {

                ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

                Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Response<Example> response) {

                        assert response.body() != null;
                        time_field.setText("Last Updated:" + " " + response.body().getDt());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }

                });
            }

        });
    }
}
```

FirstFragment.java:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // User current time, current temperature, current condition, sunrise, sunset, temperature, pressure, humidity, wind_speed, visibility, clouds
    TextView current_temp, current_output, rise_time, set_time, temp_out, Press_out, Humid_out, Ws_out, Visi_out, Cloud_out;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SecondFragment.
     */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        // For displaying weather data
        current_temp = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        current_output = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        rise_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        set_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
        temp_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
        Press_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
        Humid_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView30);
        Ws_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView33);
        Visi_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView34);
        Cloud_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView35);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void getWeatherData(String name) {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Response<Example> response) {

                assert response.body() !=null;
                current_temp.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                current_output.setText(response.body().getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                rise_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunrise() + " ");
                set_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunset() + " ");
                temp_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                Press_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getPressure() + " hpa");
                Humid_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getHumidity() + " %");
                Ws_out.setText(response.body().getWind().getSpeed() + " Km/h");
                Visi_out.setText(response.body().getVisibility() + " m");
                Cloud_out.setText(response.body().getClouds().getAll()+ " %");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Example.java:

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("coord")
    private Coord coord;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    private List<Weather> weather = null;
    @SerializedName("base")
    private String base;
    @SerializedName("main")
    private Main main;
    @SerializedName("visibility")
    private Integer visibility;
    @SerializedName("wind")
    private Wind wind;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    private Clouds clouds;
    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private PrettyTime dt;
    @SerializedName("sys")
    private Sys sys;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    private Integer timezone;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("cod")
    private Integer cod;

    public Coord getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }

    public void setCoord(Coord coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Integer getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(Integer visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    public Wind getWind() {
        return wind;
    }

    public void setWind(Wind wind) {
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    public Clouds getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    public PrettyTime getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(PrettyTime dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public Sys getSys() {
        return sys;
    }

    public void setSys(Sys sys) {
        this.sys = sys;
    }

    public Integer getTimezone() {
        return timezone;
    }

    public void setTimezone(Integer timezone) {
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(Integer cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

    public class Clouds {

        @SerializedName("all")
        private Integer all;

        public Integer getAll() {
            return all;
        }

        public void setAll(Integer all) {
            this.all = all;
        }

    }

    public class Coord {

        @SerializedName("lon")
        private Double lon;
        @SerializedName("lat")
        private Double lat;

        public Double getLon() {
            return lon;
        }

        public void setLon(Double lon) {
            this.lon = lon;
        }

        public Double getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(Double lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

    }

    public class Main {

        @SerializedName("temp")
        private Double temp;
        @SerializedName("feels_like")
        private Double feelsLike;
        @SerializedName("temp_min")
        private Double tempMin;
        @SerializedName("temp_max")
        private Double tempMax;
        @SerializedName("pressure")
        private Integer pressure;
        @SerializedName("humidity")
        private Integer humidity;

        public Double getTemp() {
            return temp;
        }

        public void setTemp(Double temp) {
            this.temp = temp;
        }

        public Double getFeelsLike() {
            return feelsLike;
        }

        public void setFeelsLike(Double feelsLike) {
            this.feelsLike = feelsLike;
        }

        public Double getTempMin() {
            return tempMin;
        }

        public void setTempMin(Double tempMin) {
            this.tempMin = tempMin;
        }

        public Double getTempMax() {
            return tempMax;
        }

        public void setTempMax(Double tempMax) {
            this.tempMax = tempMax;
        }

        public Integer getPressure() {
            return pressure;
        }

        public void setPressure(Integer pressure) {
            this.pressure = pressure;
        }

        public Integer getHumidity() {
            return humidity;
        }

        public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
            this.humidity = humidity;
        }

    }

    public class Sys {

        @SerializedName("type")
        private Integer type;
        @SerializedName("id")
        private Integer id;
        @SerializedName("country")
        private String country;
        @SerializedName("sunrise")
        @Expose
        private PrettyTime sunrise;
        @SerializedName("sunset")
        @Expose
        private PrettyTime sunset;

        public Integer getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(Integer type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public PrettyTime getSunrise() {
            return sunrise;
        }

        public void setSunrise(PrettyTime sunrise) {
            this.sunrise = sunrise;
        }

        public PrettyTime getSunset() {
            return sunset;
        }

        public void setSunset(PrettyTime sunset) {
            this.sunset = sunset;
        }

    }

    public class Weather {

        @SerializedName("id")
        private Integer id;
        @SerializedName("main")
        private String main;
        @SerializedName("description")
        private String description;
        @SerializedName("icon")
        private String icon;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getMain() {
            return main;
        }

        public void setMain(String main) {
            this.main = main;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public void setIcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }

    }

    public class Wind {

        @SerializedName("speed")
        private Double speed;
        @SerializedName("deg")
        private Integer deg;
        @SerializedName("gust")
        private Double gust;

        public Double getSpeed() {
            return speed;
        }

        public void setSpeed(Double speed) {
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        public Integer getDeg() {
            return deg;
        }

        public void setDeg(Integer deg) {
            this.deg = deg;
        }

        public Double getGust() {
            return gust;
        }

        public void setGust(Double gust) {
            this.gust = gust;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your logcat output? It will tell you the exact line that caused the crash. My suspect would be the assert body not null.

Comment: @Kilian I've added the output

Comment: Where is `Example` class defined? Asking because logcat says you're trying to invoke `getMain` on the null object of type `Example`.

Comment: Also, just on a whim, could you try to save the output of `response.getBody()` in a variable? Is there a chance that you can only get the body once (hence subsequent calls return null)?

Comment: I've included Example class in the question. How can I save the output, please?

Comment: Before the part using `response.getBody()`, you would do `final Example body = response.getBody()` and then use `body` instead of `response.getBody()` in all subsequent uses.

Comment: The reason I think this might be the issue is because I can't think otherwise how the assertion that `response.getBody() != null` succeeds but then `response.getBody()` is `null` later.

Comment: @mattf. I get error "cannot resolve method getBody in 'response'"

Comment: @BenDreg mattf 's suggestion is to create a variable out of response.body()

Comment: @tremendous7 I tried following it, but I get the above error

Comment: there are a lot of to and fro happening, do you have your full code somewhere in GitHub, it would be easy to just see what exactly you are missing and fix straight away.

Comment: @BenDreg response.getBody() is different from response.body(). create a variable out of the the latter

Comment: @dinkar_kumar seems like you've been temporary suspended or can you still access it here if i share?

Comment: @tremendous7 this didn't work and it's incomplete because it doesn't throw
a toast message.

Comment: @Chinez yes pelase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP said `I just need the best method to handle the exceptions`

Let me give two examples for your case to avoid the crash and show toast for both Activity and Fragment.

- **try/catch**

Update your Activity `onResponse` like below.

```
                public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                    try {
                        time_field.setText("Last Updated:" + " " + response.body().getDt());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        time_field.setText("Last Updated: Unknown");
                        Log.e("TAG", "No City found");
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No City found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

Update your Fragment `onResponse like below

```
public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

            try {
                current_temp.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                current_output.setText(response.body().getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                rise_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunrise() + " ");
                set_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunset() + " ");
                temp_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                Press_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getPressure() + " hpa");
                Humid_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getHumidity() + " %");
                Ws_out.setText(response.body().getWind().getSpeed() + " Km/h");
                Visi_out.setText(response.body().getVisibility() + " m");
                Cloud_out.setText(response.body().getClouds().getAll() + " %");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "No City found");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No City found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

- **null check**

Update your Activity `onResponse` like below.

```
                    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        time_field.setText("Last Updated:" + " " + response.body().getDt());
                    } else {
                        time_field.setText("Last Updated: Unknown");
                        Log.e("TAG", "No City found");
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No City found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
```

Update your Fragment `onResponse` like below

```
public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                current_temp.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                current_output.setText(response.body().getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                rise_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunrise() + " ");
                set_time.setText(response.body().getSys().getSunset() + " ");
                temp_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
                Press_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getPressure() + " hpa");
                Humid_out.setText(response.body().getMain().getHumidity() + " %");
                Ws_out.setText(response.body().getWind().getSpeed() + " Km/h");
                Visi_out.setText(response.body().getVisibility() + " m");
                Cloud_out.setText(response.body().getClouds().getAll() + " %");
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", "No City found");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No City found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
```

**Note:** There is a bit of scope to improve your code and design a better, like to avoid an extra call to API on search click, one from Activity and another in the fragment. But all those suggestion will be out of the scope of this question, So I will stick to OP request which is `I just need the best method to handle the exceptions`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Response<Example> response) {
    
           assert response.body() !=null;
    
    if(response.body().getMain()==null && response.body().getWeather()!=null && all other field!=null){
    yourErrorTextview.setText("No City found");
    allOtherField.setText();
    }
    else if(response.body().getMain()!=null && response.body().getWeather()!=null && all other field!=null){
             current_temp.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp() + " ℃");
             allOtherField.setText();
    }}
```

Comment: Please the "yourErrorTextview" part. am I to create an error text view and if I'm to, where should I place it in?

Comment: Please how do I do that?

Comment: just create errorTextView with visibility "gone" by default.If getMain() is null ,setVisibility "Visible" to errorTextView. Then errorTextView .setText("No City found"); OR Just Create Toast .

Comment: I want to create toast but on YouTube, they only explained how to create it with button. Can you suggest the best way I can do it? And I want to do it in a different layout. Not my fragment's own

Comment: I used your full suggestion(using error textview)and still got the same error.  I even got some runtime like "&& cannot be applied to boolean"

Answer (score 0):

According to the log you get a success response with a body but `getMain` returns `null`.

You can prevent this by adding some null checks around getMain. Make sure to check the possibility of null in the api documentation.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary because getMain only returns null when I search an unavailable city which is very normal. For instance, I can get the temperature for London but not djsj. All I need is to catch/stop the exception for that and Also tell the user "no city found" Which is very necessary.

Comment: Just telling you what the error says. You get a successful response from the api and apparently main is null which causes your NullPointerException. You could wrap everything in a try catch and show an error if you want.

Comment: Main is only null when an unavailable city is searched

Comment: So @kilian explained what to do to "stop the exception responsible for that". Are you just looking for someone to explain how to do a toast mesage?

Comment: @atmas "You can prevent this by adding some null checks around getMain" Is not enough way to explain it to me. I'm inexperienced with these concepts. How do I add null checks? The api documentation said nothing on the possibility of null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch block in catch you are getting exception you can toast message city not found so your app will not crash.